# Why renaming gzip file using Python is not renaming the actual file in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, gzip

I am writing into a compressed file using the gzip module of Python3.7 and then renaming that file. The expectation here is it should rename the actual name of the file as well but that's not happening in Windows. (In Linux it's working as expected.)

Code:

```
result_file = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\test_data.csv.zip.filepart"
with gzip.open(result_file, "wb") as f_res:
    f_res.write("some data".encode())
# Rename after successfully writing into file
os.rename(result_file, result_file[:len(result_file)-len('.filepart')])
```

On successful execution of the above code, In Windows, It creates a file named "test_data.csv.zip" and after extracting the file, I get the actual CSV with "some data" string but the file name remains "**test_data.csv.zip.filepart**" only whereas in Linux, after extraction, I'm getting "**test_data.csv**" which is the expected result.

Is there a way I get the same behavior in Windows also?

Comment: `Windows` might be a bit broad, please share more about the Windows configuration where the code fails, the versions of windows that you've tried, and any solutions you tried and how they failed.

Comment: Sounds like Windows is naming the file based on the gzip header. You can open the file beforehand, pass it as `fileobj=..` and then set `filename=..` to the filename you want it to have in the gzipped file

Comment: You should not be calling a gzip file ".zip". The correct suffix is ".gz". zip files and gzip files are two entirely different things.

Comment: When I run your code on Windows 10, Python 3.9, writes the file, and renames it, but not as you expect. For me, it renames the file to `test_data.csv.zip` which is what *I* expect from reading your code. I don't quite understand why are you expecting code that truncates the filename by 9 characters  (`len(".filepart')`) to remove the suffix `".zip.filepart"`. *Inside the `.gz` file* the name of the file is `test_data.csv.zip.filepart` but that is something `os.rename()` will not know how to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an intermediate name to be used such as `data.csv.filepart` that is renamed afterward, then open the intermediate file as binary, and construct a `GzipFile` specifying the uncompressed filename desired and pass in the file object：

```
import gzip
import os

with open('data.csv.filepart','wb') as f:
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename='data.csv',mode='wb',fileobj=f) as g:
        g.write(b'some data')

os.rename('data.csv.filepart','data.csv.gz')
```

Filename will be "data.csv.filepart" while writing, "data.csv.gz" when completed, and extract to "data.csv".

Optionally, if you want text processing instead of binary, wrap the `GzipFile` object in a `TextIOWrapper`, and if desired you can use the `csv` module to write your CSV with Unicode strings compatible with Excel.  Make sure to save the source in UTF-8 encoding due to the non-ASCII characters：

```
import gzip
import os
import io
import csv

with open('data.csv.filepart','wb') as f:
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename='data.csv',mode='wb',fileobj=f) as g:
        with io.TextIOWrapper(g,encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as t:
            w = csv.writer(t)
            w.writerow(['Header1','Header2','Header3'])
            w.writerow(['data1','你好吗？','\N{PILE OF POO}'])

os.rename('data.csv.filepart','data.csv.gz')
```

[image: Result in Excel]

Comment: As per my use case, "filepart" should be a suffix or prefix (Or anywhere to know the file is not a complete file) of the filename while writing to the file and once written successfully then the "filepart" suffix should be removed. So, This solution won't work in my case.

Comment: @JayShah See edit using using `GzipFile` construction.

Comment: That really helped. Thank you !!